# ¿Cómo Validar una imagen en base64?

Tags: java, base64

Para mi proyecto requiero almacenar una imagen en mongo, se acordó que sería en base64; ya se puede convertir, almacenar y regresar a la forma original, la imagen la recibo de móviles que consumen mi servicio REST, mi duda es: ¿Cómo puedo validar que la cadena que recibo se trata de una imagen con formato JPG?

Comment: [determine if file is an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670546/determine-if-file-is-an-image) quizas algunos de esos ejemplo te ayude.

Comment: Incorpora algo de tu codigo, para que tu pregunta no sea cerrada y podamos ayudarte de mejor manera. muestranos como recuperas la imagen(base64).

Answer (score 0):

No se como estas descodificando o recuperando la imagen, pero aquí te muestro un ejemplo de como podrías resolverlo.

Decodifique la cadena `Base64` en una matriz de bytes y luego descubrir el tipo de imagen, algo como esto:

```
String delims="[,]";
String[] parts = base64ImageString.split(delims);
String imageString = parts[1];
byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decode(imageString );

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);

//Descubrir la imagen
String mimeType = null;
String fileExtension = null;
try 
{
    mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is); //mimeType es algo así como "image/jpeg"
    String delimiter="[/]";
    String[] tokens = mimeType.split(delimiter);
    fileExtension = tokens[1];
} 
catch (IOException ioException) { }
```

> Lo que te puede dar el resultado deseado es esto: 
>   `mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(inputstream);` que viene siendo como `"image/jpeg"`

Nota: Estoy vía móvil en este momento, por cualquier validación faltánte el código, no la he probado.